# Cannot set boolean values in LocalStorage?

Tags: javascript

I noticed that I cannot set boolean values in `localStorage`?

```
localStorage.setItem("item1", true);
alert(localStorage.getItem("item1") + " | " + (localStorage.getItem("item1") == true));
```

Always alerts `true | false` when I try to test `localStorage.getItem("item1") == "true"` it alerts true ... How can I set an item in `localStorage` to true?

Even if it's a string, I thought only `===` would check the type?

So

```
alert("true" == true); // should be true?
```

Answer (score 90, accepted):

[Firefox's implementation of Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/dom/storage#Storage) can only store strings, but on [2009 September](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-webstorage-20090910/#the-storage-interface), W3C modified the draft to accept any data. <del>The implementation (still) isn't caught up yet</del> (*see Edit below*).

So in your case the boolean is converted to a string.

As for why `"true" != true`, as written in [the description of Equal (`==`) in MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)*:

> If the two operands are not of the same type, JavaScript converts the operands then applies strict comparison. If either operand is a number or a boolean, the operands are converted to **numbers** if possible; else if either operand is a string, the other operand is converted to a string if possible.

Note that the string is converted to a *Number* instead of a *Boolean*. Since `"true"` converted to a number is `NaN`, it will not be equal to anything, so `false` is returned.

(*: For the actual standard, see ECMA-262 §11.9.3 “The Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm”)

---

**Edit:** The `setItem` interface was reverted to accept strings only on the [2011 Sept 1st draft](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-webstorage-20110901/) to match the behavior of existing implementations, as none of the vendors are interested in supporting storing non-strings. See https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=12111 for detail.

Comment: *If either operand is a number or a boolean, the operands are converted to **numbers** if possible* - I totally didn't realize that.  I thought if one were a string, the other was cast to a string.  Cheers (+1).

Comment: @Andy, check this [useful notes](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/notes/note-2-ecmascript-equality-operators/) on the subject.

Answer (score 164):

For the moment, all the implementations [Safari](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/Name-ValueStorage/Name-ValueStorage.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007256-CH6-SW1), WebKit, Chrome, [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API) and [IE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem), are following [the current version](https://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-webstorage-20090423/) of the WebStorage standard, where the value of the storage items can be only a string.

An option would be to use JSON `parse` and `stringify` method to *serialize* and *deserialize* the data, as I suggested some time ago in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage/), for example:

```js
var value = "true";
console.log(JSON.parse(value) === true); // true
```

Comment: This will obviously break if the string passed in `value` is not valid JSON (for example `JSON.parse("a random string")`)

Comment: True @AdonisK. But if he is using JSON.stringify when setting all values then he is able to offload the responsibility of outputting valid JSON to the library. And that is a very stable library.

Comment: The [current specification](//html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webstorage.html#the-storage-interface) defines an interface where `getItem` only returns a string or `null` and `setItem` only accepts a string. Reading the [other answer](/a/3263248/4642212), it doesn’t seem this is going to change, so the wording in this answer is outdated.

Comment: yeah — it's not an _old_ version, it's _the only_ version.

Answer (score 24):

My solutions:

```
function tytPreGetBool(pre) {
    return localStorage.getItem(pre) === 'true';
}
```

Comment: @koppor Maybe because if getItem would ever return a boolean, then this method will yield false results, since `true == 'true'` is `false`.

Comment: ..or plain `localStorage.getItem(pre)==='true'` without the rest

Comment: @koppor why is this down-voted? because the self-righteous stackers are overflowing, literally :)

Comment: "? true : false" is unnecessary since localStorage.getItem(pre) == 'true' already gives you a boolean result

Answer (score 8):

I'd like to point out that it might be kinda easier just to wrap plain boolean value inside object and then, using `JSON.stringify` create local storage content and other way around, `JSON.parse` to retrive it:

```
let storeMe = {
  myBool: true
}

localStorage.setItem('test', JSON.stringify(storeMe))
let result = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('test'))
```

Answer (score 7):

This is related to CMS’s answer.

Here’s a little function I’ve been using to handle the parsing part of this issue (the function will keep doing the Right Thing after the browser implementations catch up with the spec, so no need to remember to change out code later):

```
function parse(type) {
   return typeof type == 'string' ? JSON.parse(type) : type;
}
```

Comment: Isn't this unnecessary compared to JSON.parse? JSON.parse("true") and JSON.parse(true) already both return true, so will still do the right thing after browsers implement boolean localstorage

Answer (score 3):

Use [store.js](https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js/#user-content-api):

```
localStorage.setItem('isUser', true)
localStorage.getItem('isUser') === "true" //true
npm i -D store
```

↓

```
store.get('isUser')  //true
```

Comment: But is it really necessary to include a whole library just for this simple string-to-boolean conversion task?

Answer (score 2):

What I usually do is just save the value in LocalStore as a Boolean, and then retrieve with a parsing method, just to be sure for all browsers. My method below is customized for my business logic. Sometimes I might store smth as 'no' and still need `false` in return

```
function toBoolean(str) {
    if (typeof str === 'undefined' || str === null) {
        return false;
    } else if (typeof str === 'string') {           
        switch (str.toLowerCase()) {
        case 'false':
        case 'no':
        case '0':
        case "":
            return false;
        default:
            return true;
        }
    } else if (typeof str === 'number') {
        return str !== 0
    }
    else {return true;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if LocalStorage can save boolean values but I can tell you that when you do `alert("true" == true);` it will never evaluate to true because you are implicitly comparing a string to a boolean. That is why to set boolean values you use `true` instead of `"true"`.

Comment: What about alert("1"==1)? Javascript is a strange (and inconsistent) beasty.

Comment: @spender: that's because the right operand is cast to a string for the comparison.  `"1" === 1` would actually return false.

Comment: @Kenny: whoops *facepalm*, thanks for the correction :-) I was mixed up because of how booleans cast to strings.

Answer (score 1):

`eval` can also be used **carefully** under some cases.

```
console.log(eval("true") === true) //true
```

Comment: Avoid `eval` since it can be unsafe. Prefer `JSON.parse("true")`.

Answer (score 1):

When I need to store a **flag** I usually do:
`localStorage.f_active = true` (stored value is 'true' and it's fine)
`if localStorage.f_active` — passes

and to unflag:
`delete localStorage.f_active`
`if localStorage.f_active` — doesn't pass (returned value is undefined)

Answer (score 1):

eval can also be used carefully under some cases.

```js
localstorage.setItem("yourValue","true")

const yourValue = eval(
     localStorage.getItem("yourValue") as string
   );
 console.log(keepConnected) //true
 console.log(!keepConnected) //false
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot set a boolean value for a key in the local storage, this is what I do (the code is in TypeScript for clarity). Also, let's pretend that we're saving the `Remember User` option from some page (login or something else).

Set the key to a constant and export it, so you can utilize it in other components/files:

```
export const REMEMBER_USER_FLAG: string = 'remember_user';
```

Setter:

```
storeRememberUserData(rememberUser: boolean = false): void {
  localStorage.setItem(REMEMBER_USER_FLAG, JSON.stringify(String(rememberUser)));
}
```

And then the getter:

```
isRememberUserSet(): boolean {
  return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(REMEMBER_USER_FLAG)) === 'true';
}
```

Which will serve as a boolean and you can use as a flag.