# Store booleans in javascript's localStorage?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot set boolean values in LocalStorage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263161/cannot-set-boolean-values-in-localstorage)

So i've been trying to get localStorage.test to store a boolean forever...

http://jsfiddle.net/abhi/aVmyt/

And it always ends up storing as a string.

Play around with the various localStorage variables created in the fiddle by changing the condition used in the if statement, and do lemme know if you manage to store a boolean...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The W3C [Storage interface](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#the-storage-interface) specifies that values (and keys) are strings:

> Each Storage object provides access to a list of key/value pairs,
>   which are sometimes called items. Keys are strings. Any string
>   (including the empty string) is a valid key. Values are similarly
>   strings

Comment: Wow, must have annoyed someone. A random downvote nearly 4 years in the making…