# A false Variable Doesn't Validate as false

Tags: javascript, local-storage, logical-operators

I am having trouble understanding some weird behavior in my code and I am wondering if anyone can tell me what I am doing wrong?

I have a Boolean variable `isWaiting` and it is saved as `false` in `localStorage` and when it is retrieved, it is shown as `false` but when you do validation, it doesn't see it that way. Here is a small code to replicate my issue:

```
(function(){
    localStorage.setItem("isWaiting", false);
    var isWaiting = localStorage.getItem("isWaiting");
    console.log("isWaiting = " + isWaiting)
    console.log("Is isWaiting False? " + Boolean(isWaiting === false));
    // I have tried it as this as well
    console.log("Is isWaiting False? " + (isWaiting === false));
})()
```

#### Should get:

> isWaiting = false
>
> Is isWaiting False? true

#### Produces:

> isWaiting = false
>
> Is isWaiting False? false ⬅ **This is clearly wrong**, so why is this happening?

What am I doing wrong? Is the boolean value of false somehow getting mangled in the `localStorage` process and if so, how would I account for it, if not, then what is wrong?

---

### Solution Update:10/09/18

Based on the kind replies helping me confirm that indeed my suspicion that the LS process is butchering the value type was correct and more specifically the solution provided by @bhojendra-rauniyar, I have changed the code to correct the type right at the moment of retrieval and then handling it as normal throughout the code avoiding having a ton of added code and it seems to have done the trick, thank you to all for your help.

```
...
    var isWaiting = Boolean(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("isWaiting")));
...
```

Comment: another useful thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7061702/store-booleans-in-javascripts-localstorage

Comment: @Narendra thank you for linking that, which was a duplicate, but following down the rabbit hole, I found (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263161/cannot-set-boolean-values-in-localstorage) which suggests a reason but it was posted back in 2010, does it still hold true I wonder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Local storage stores the value in string. So, even if you use `Boolean('false')` will return true. Because it's not empty string. Anything that has value in string is to be `true`. To get around this, you may use:

```
Boolean(JSON.parse('false')) // false
Boolean(JSON.parse('true')) // true
```

So, you can do:

```
Boolean(JSON.parse(isWaiting))
```

---

Alternatively, you may also compare with string:

```
String(false) === 'false' // true
```

So, using:

```
console.log(String(isWaiting)) // will return false
```

Comment: Thank you, while the solution presented by others below would be less code, I think I like the stability and assurance of your method. I am going to try and test the code fix and if that resolves it then I will be back quick to mark it.

Answer (score 1):

[localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem) sets values as string.
In your example
Boolean(isWaiting === false) -> false
but if you check
`Boolean(isWaiting === 'false')` -> this will give you true

Comment: Ok, so you are suggesting just validate the string itself, thank you I didn't expect that LS would turn everything string only, live and learn.

Answer (score 0):

LocalStorage will save values in the string and you cannot compare a string to boolean. So you need to compare it like this:

```
(function(){
    localStorage.setItem("isWaiting", false);
    var isWaiting = localStorage.getItem("isWaiting");
    console.log("isWaiting = " + isWaiting)
    console.log("Is isWaiting False? " + Boolean(isWaiting === 'false'));
    // I have tried it as this as well
    console.log("Is isWaiting False? " + (isWaiting === 'false'));
})()
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, Narendra gave the same technique and Bhojendra provided an alternative, so I think I can get make due for now.