# sessionStorage setItem returns true or false

Tags: javascript, html, sessionstorage

I'm trying to figure out what the `setItem` method from `sessionStorage` returns. As far as I could get, the following code returns `undefined`:

```
var set = sessionStorage.setItem('foo', 'bar');
console.log(set);
```

I need to know if the item was successfully set or if it failed. How can I accomplish this without knowing the return?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot set boolean values in LocalStorage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263161/cannot-set-boolean-values-in-localstorage)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at the [`sessionStorage` specification](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#storage-0).

This line:

```
setter creator void setItem(DOMString key, DOMString value);
```

Tells us `setItem` doesn't return anything. (`void` is the return value, there)

---

You can check if the item was set like this:

```
if (sessionStorage.getItem('myValue') == null){
    // myValue was not set
}else{
    // myValue was set
}
```

Comment: I think this will do for now... assuming that if something goes wrong, NULL is returned.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage) is a guide on `sessionStorage` from the Mozilla Developer Network. It appears that `sessionStorage.setItem(name, value)` does not return anything.

However, if you manually wanted to check, you could try something like this:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('make', 'Ford');

/* Returns null if it cannot find the item in sessionStorage. */
if(sessionStorage.getItem('make')) {
    /* Session storage set successfully. */
} else {
    /* Session storage did not set successfully. */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use try catch expression, since the method throws an exception if the session is full, as stated in the [specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem) :

```
try { sessionStorage.setItem('foo', 'bar'); }
catch(oops) {
     // maybe no more space, try to free
     localStorage.removeItem('foo');
     sessionStorage.setItem('foo', 'bar');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to add in case someone will have the same issue as me. (im a beginner in js btw).

I was following [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39127730/jquery-if-condition-is-false-but-still-executed/39127785) and trying the below but the if was firing when entering the page (on first load).

```
sessionStorage.setItem('test',false);    
if (sessionStorage.getItem('test') != "false") {
   ..........
}
```

What did it for me was **changing != to ==**. So in my case it looks like this:

```
//other function that sets session and reloads
sessionStorage.setItem('reload', 'false');
location.reload();

//then the if after reload
if ( sessionStorage.getItem('reload') == 'false' ) {
//whatever you want here
//setting it true again so it doesn't fire when I manually reload.
sessionStorage.setItem('reload', 'true'); 
}
```

I find it a bit counterintuitive because you'd think to set the session to true and then fire the if if session != false... but hey it works, doesn't fire on first page load and then fires when i execute the page reload.