# Localstorage not working as intended in firefox. Returns object of null

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, local-storage, firefox-addon-sdk

I was porting a chrome extension to firefox. Everything is fine in chrome but the following code generates error in firefox.

```
localStorage.setItem("display_tooltip", false);

data = localStorage.getItem('display_tooltip');
    if(data.display_tooltip)                  //line where error occurs
        display_tooltip = true;
    else
        display_tooltip = false;
```

I get an error on firefox saying data is null. Where am I doing it wrong. The same code works perfectly when I run the chrome extension.
I am using firefox addon-sdk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[localStorage](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#the-storage-interface) stores strings not [booleans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263161/cannot-set-boolean-values-in-localstorage), hence you'll have to compare accordingly. And you need to check for `data` variable instead of `data.display_tooltip`, as:

```
localStorage.setItem("display_tooltip", false);
data = localStorage.getItem('display_tooltip'); 
// variavle 'data' holds value stored in 'display_tooltip' variable
if(data == "true") {
    //your code
    alert("True");
}
else {
    //false, your code
    alert("False");
}
```

Demo:: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lof4jkLa/)

Answer (score 1):

It will not work in any browser.

You are setting '**false**' to the var `data` so `data.display_tooltip` does not exists.

Just ask for the value of `data`:

```
if (data == 'true')
  display_tooltip = true;
else
 display_tooltip = false;
```

Note that `localStorage` does not store **booleans** so you need to ask for the '**true**' string when you check the value.

Answer (score 0):

you data is:

```
data = localStorage.getItem('display_tooltip')
```

Why you using `data. display_tooltip` to check? Just`if (data) { ... }` . Maybe you need to check the type of `data`. Maybe it is string of true or false, but not bool.