# Check if local storage value is equal to

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know how to check a the value of an item stored in local storage is true or false.

This is what i have , but the if statement isnt working.

```
function setCBT(){
localStorage.setItem('testObject', true);

}


function alertLocalStorage(){
var object = localStorage.getItem('testObject');

if(object == true) {

   alert("This item is true");
}
else {

       alert("This item is false");

}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> all the implementations Safari, WebKit, Chorme, Firefox and IE, are following an old version of the WebStorage standard, where the value of the storage items can be only a string.

Thus you need to compare the value with string:

```
 if(object == "true") {
```

Here is the **[Alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3263222/1719752)** posted by **[CMS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5445/cms)**.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use

```
if(object) { 
    // true 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `JSON.parse()`.The `JSON.parse()` method parses a string as JSON, optionally transforming the value produced by parsing.

```
if(JSON.parse(object)) {

   alert("This item is true");
}
```

Note using **JSON.parse()**

```
JSON.parse('{}');              // {}
JSON.parse('true');            // true
JSON.parse('"foo"');           // "foo"
JSON.parse('[1, 5, "false"]'); // [1, 5, "false"]
JSON.parse('null');            // null
```

[JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)