# Boolean toggle and save to localStorage not toggling addClass

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to do a `addToWishlist` function so item can be saved for later viewing, when I save the `boolean` value `true/false` in the `localStorage` its toggling but not the `.addClass` jQuery. I'm saving it to `localStorage` so if user refresh the page it still holds the items they've saved.

How can I fix the `addClass` toggle properly, based on the value saved in `localStorage true/false`?

```
<button onclick="wishList()" class="btn btn-default wishlist"><i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add to wishlist</button>
```

```
var wishlistItems = localStorage.getItem('wishlists');
var addToWishlist = false;
function wishList() {
    addToWishlist = !addToWishlist;
    localStorage.setItem('wishlists', addToWishlist);
    if(wishlistItems === false) {
      $(this).find('.fa').removeClass('add-to-wishlist');
    }
    $(this).find('.fa').addClass('add-to-wishlist');
}
```

[Plnkr sample](https://plnkr.co/edit/LWREYRpYRagK7xvtNjnv?p=preview)

Comment: Ok. So what is the question?

Comment: Yeah sorry I missed that haha, how can I fixed the `addClass` bit based on the boolean value saved in the `localStorage`?

Comment: Appreciate if you explain your downvote.

Comment: I didn't downvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many answers talking about using `toggleClass()`, which is fine - but that's not your real problem.

You're using `$(this)` to try and find an element, but `this` isn't referencing what you think it's referencing. In this instance, its the scope of the `wishList()` function - not the element that was clicked.

Add `event` into your onclick event;

```
<button onclick="wishList(event)" ...>...</button>
```

Then for your `wishList()` function use `event.target` to reference the clicked element;

```
function wishList(event) {
    var element = event.target;
    localStorage.setItem('wishlists', !addToWishlist);
    $(element).find('.fa').toggleClass('add-to-wishlist', !addToWishlist);
}
```

To add the class when you load the page, you just need to grab the data from local storage, and then add the class if required.

However, as you'll need to reference the element directly rather than based off the event above - it may be better to *always* reference the element directly anyway.

For example, just have this inside your `$(document).ready()` function;

```
var lsWishList = localStorage.getItem('wishlists');
if(lsWishList == true) {
    $(".wishlist").find('.fa').addClass('add-to-wishlist');
}
```

**A note about what's TRUE**

Be careful when using this comparison. A string value will return as TRUE (with `==`) - and as Local Storage can only be reliably used to store strings you might need rethink how you're storing that data.

Comment: but `$(this)` would work if you're using `.click()` event instead, right? now my problem is how to retain `true` state so when page is refreshed it still has `add-to-wishlist` class.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include an example. But, you need to be careful about what you're thinking is `TRUE` and what you're thinking is `FALSE`.

Comment: `== true` doesn't seems to be a `Boolean` but a `string`, so when I toggle it to `true` then refresh it then toggle it again stays to `true` state when it should be `"false"`.

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned in my answer - Local Storage can't store Boolean values.

Comment: so I changed `true` to `"true"` instead but that still happening, when I re-toggle the button after being `"true"` it stays `"true"` still. Sample https://plnkr.co/edit/LWREYRpYRagK7xvtNjnv?p=preview

Comment: `JSON.parse()` would convert the value to `Boolean` but my last comment is still an issue.

Comment: Examine the console logs I've put in; https://plnkr.co/edit/TRcqbryxkRrbvPQACN7W?p=preview - You'll see that it requires 2 clicks of the wishlist button to toggle the Locally Stored value to false. This is because your `addToWishlist = !addToWishlist;` line is designed to work with Boolean values, not strings.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141351/discussion-between-thebluefox-and-mrnew).

Answer (score 3):

You could use a conditional `toggleClass()` :

```
$(this).find('.fa').toggleClass('some-class', !wishlistItems);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is better use of `toggleClass` +1

Comment: Frankly, I'd remove the first part of this answer. There we go, perfect. +1

Answer (score 2):

A shorter way would be to use `toggleClass`, which can take a boolean value as a second parameter:

```
$(this).find('.fa').toggleClass('add-to-wishlist', !wishlistItems);
```

Comment: localStorage contains **string**. Non-empty string is truthy.

Answer (score 0):

Try with jquery's [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

```
  $(this).find('.fa').toggleClass('add-to-wishlist');
```

Method will change to

```
function wishList() 
{
    localStorage.setItem('wishlists', !(addToWishlist=="true"));
    $(this).find('.fa').toggleClass('add-to-wishlist');
}
```

or adding state to `toggleClass`

```
var addToWishlist = localStorage.getItem('wishlists');
function wishList() 
{
    addToWishlist = !( addToWishlist == "true" || addToWishlist == true );
    localStorage.setItem('wishlists', addToWishlist );
    $(this).find('.fa').toggleClass('add-to-wishlist', addToWishlist );
}
```

Comment: Oh that's neat don't need `if` statement, how can I make the class stay when page is refreshed?

Comment: `!(addToWishlist=="true");` what? That's horrible.

Comment: @Cerbrus if the `addToWishlist` is true, it will change the value to false or true.

Comment: ... And that's even worse. Look at the condition used in the OP.

Comment: ohh, missed the part where `addToWishlist ` is different from `wishlistitems`. Misread the question, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

`wishlistItems` always returns false as it it declared and assigned outside function.
Add `wishlistItems = localStorage.getItem('wishlists')` inside function after assgining data to `localStorage`

```
var wishlistItems = localStorage.getItem('wishlists');
var addToWishlist = false;
function wishList() {
    addToWishlist = !addToWishlist;
    localStorage.setItem('wishlists', addToWishlist);
    wishlistItems = localStorage.getItem('wishlists')
     $(".wishlist").find('.fa').toggleClass('add-to-wishlist');
}
```

**Updated Answer as per the comment**

As per **[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263161/cannot-set-boolean-values-in-localstorage)**, we can't save boolean values to Localstorage

```
function wishList(onload) {
  var addToWish = (localStorage.getItem('wishlists')  == "true");
  var wishlistItems = (onload)?addToWish:!addToWish;
    localStorage.setItem('wishlists', wishlistItems);
     $(".wishlist").find('.fa').addClass('add-to-wishlist');
     if(wishlistItems === false){
       $(".wishlist").find('.fa').removeClass('add-to-wishlist');
     }
}
$(function(){
  wishList(true);
})
```

Call same function onload also. 
**`wishList(true)`** pass a variable to persist the wishlist value onlaod.

**[updated working example demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/SCeGKkloMiNW37pq4kl5?p=preview)**

Comment: how can you retain `true` state class when you refresh the page?

Comment: @MrNew please check the updated Answer, I've added working plnkr example also

Comment: Sure, but enforcing `true/false` state as soon as the page loads? This won't work if jquery functions is wrapped in `$(function() {});` as it will toggle every time the page is refreshed. 

updated my plnkr to this
https://plnkr.co/edit/LWREYRpYRagK7xvtNjnv?p=preview