# Why "false" from Local Storage is "true" for the model?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, local-storage

There is this Vuetify alert set up:

```
<v-alert color="info" icon="storage" dismissible v-model="alert">
    {{ alertText }}
</v-alert>
```

And here's in the `data`:

```
data () {
  return {
    alert: localStorage.getItem('displayLsAlert') || true,
    (...)
}
```

I'm watching for changes of the alert (when user clicks on the "close" icon, the value changes to "false"):

```
watch: {
  alert: function () {
    localStorage.setItem('displayLsAlert', false)
  }
},
```

When closing the alert, an entry `displayLsAlert` appears in Local Storage, its value is `false`. So, it should not display the alert upon next visit, right? But it does. Whenever I come back to the page, the alert keeps on appearing.

Should the `false` value be wrapped or turned into different type?

Comment: This answer might have some helpful info for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263161/cannot-set-boolean-values-in-localstorage

Comment: `false || true` is always true

Comment: @Zze: works the same with `|| true` removed.