# checkbox state always turn true when false in localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, local-storage

For some reason, when loading the page, the checkbox `checked` state is always `true` and when it's supposed to be set to the actual storage value `false`

```js
if (localStorage.getItem("diff_search") == undefined) {
        localStorage.setItem("diff_search", false)
}

document.getElementById("diff_search_box").checked = localStorage.getItem("diff_search")
// localStorage.getItem("diff_search") = false
// document.getElementById("diff_search_box").checked become true for no reason here

document.getElementById("diff_search_box").addEventListener("change", function() {
   if (this.checked){
       localStorage.setItem("diff_search", true)
   } else {
       localStorage.setItem("diff_search", false)
   }
});
```

The problem is not about storing the value, but actually setting the state of the checkbox.

I also Know that localStorage can store Boolean, contrary to what some comment say, after all, localStorage is (i could be wrong here) a json file i can get value from using keys.

to Finish, just doing

```js
document.getElementById("diff_search_box").checked = true;
```

won't change the checkbox state and it will stay the same as before

example:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lrqfwamv/
as you can see, after reloading the page, the state is not conserved and is static
edit: updated code in link since auto conversion to Boolean doesn't seem to occur for people testing

Comment: localStorage only stores strings. Anything not a string will have `toString()` called on it before storage. Therefore, `getItem` will always return a string. Strings with value (not empty) are always truthy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot set boolean values in LocalStorage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263161/cannot-set-boolean-values-in-localstorage)

Comment: title clearly say that the checkbox never change state, it has nothing to do with localStorage like stated in the code.  
i also know Heretic's comment is wrong since i managed to store all kind of type of variable in localStorage in the past, it's just like a json file after all.

Comment: @Gess1t - After reading this in your comment: "_it's just like a json file after all_", may I recommend you read this: [What is JSON anyway](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON). TDLR; JSON is text - a.k.a a String.

Comment: May I recommend you provide a [example] that demonstrates the behavior you've described?

Comment: @RandyCasburn added a link to jsfiddle with the same issue occurring

Comment: @Gess1t check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/2ryu397f/

Comment: There's a very simple test to determine the truthfulness of my statement. Run `localStorage.setItem('test', false); console.log(localStorage.getItem('test') ? true : false);` and it will log `true`, because the string "false" is truthy. In fact, run `localStorage.setItem('test', false); console.log(Boolean(localStorage.getItem('test')));` and it will log `true`, because "false" is truthy.

Answer (score 0):

localStorage stores only strings and `Boolean("false") === true`. You have to convert that string back into the correct boolean value.

```
document.getElementById("diff_search_box").checked = "true" === localStorage.getItem("diff_search")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert or parse the value back to a Boolean, because localStorage can **only store strings**.

If you try to save a *non-string* value into localStorage, it calls `value.toString()` before storing it.

Here is a way to reconstruct the boolean value, by simply comparing it with "true":

```js
const stringValue = "false"; // fixed value, can't use localStorage in a Snippet
const boolValue = stringValue === "true";

console.log(boolValue);
console.log(typeof boolValue);
```

In general it is recommended to use `JSON.stringify()` when saving an object, combined with `JSON.parse()` when you want to reconstruct the original object again.

Answer (score 0):

first :  make sure the `id` of your checkbox is the same as you use in your javascript code

```html
<input type="checkbox"  id="diff_search_box">
```

this way, with `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()` and double question mark operator to check undefined values :

```js
const diffSearkCB = document.getElementById('diff_search_box')

// on start if localStorage.getItem('diff_search') is undefined, the checkbox use false as default value
diffSearkCB.checked = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('diff_search')) ?? false 

diffSearkCB.addEventListener('change', function() {
  localStorage.setItem('diff_search', JSON.stringify(diffSearkCB.checked))
})
```

[image: proof]

Comment: this won't change anything as the state of the checkbox can't be altered at all, also, this code is far from clean from my point of view, also, localStorage already return a Boolean for use by default on my side

Comment: @Gess1t  your are wrong, It is not possible to store a boolean value in the localStorage, only text. you therefore need a function for transforming text to a boolean, whether it is true or false, that's pretty much what the JSON.stringify and parse methods do

Comment: still, your answer doesn't work as the state of the checkbox is static and therefore cannot be changed.

Comment: @Gess1t I wonder what test you did, I tested it myself before posting this answer here, and everything is working fine

Comment: i tested the case in the link, and as you can see, after the value in localStorage is set to true, the checkbox won't turn true when reloading the page, it stay unchecked and false

Comment: @Gess1t look at my own test image that I added: after a reload the localStorage returns the correct value

Comment: your image doesn't change the fact i don't obtain what you obtain with the code in my fiddle

Comment: @Gess1t nope, you cannot use the localStorage methods on fiddle, because they are disabled there. just use your browser natively to do this test